# chrome-post man, volley or OK-http giving different result

Tags: android

I'm getting response when I run through chrome-post man, same parameter and link  volley or OK-HTTP giving failed status. API link and parameter I have verified, is there any other possibility of getting wrong result.

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

1)If u have not start the server that time giving error 
2) If u have not Authnticate properly()